# Using VBA, save and share file as XLSM

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, xlsm

I am using the following code to save an Excel sheet as PDF and send it as mail attachment.

I can't manage to simultaneously save it as xlsm file to the same path and file name and also attach it to an email that I have generated for the pdf file.

```
Dim varResult As Variant
Dim ActBook As Workbook

varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
            "PDF (*.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Save File", _
             InitialFileName:="Example"


ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords") = "Example"
'PDF EXPORT
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=varResult, Type:=xlTypePDF, OpenAfterPublish:=True, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True


Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
    .To = "Example@mail.com"
    .Subject = "Example"
    .Body = "Example"
    .Attachments.Add varResult
    
    .Send        
    End With
```

I tried to copy the "varResult" part and replace "pdf" with "xlsm".

```vb
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=varResult, Type:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True
```

I get

> "Runtime error 75"

Comment: Which errors and in which line?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it says "Runtime error 75". I have tried to add the following: 
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=varResult, Type:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True

Comment: In which line of code does the error occur?

Comment: It marks the line that I have added in the comment. I have placed it directly under the line that saves it as pdf.

Comment: `ExportAsFixedFormat` only supports `PDF` and `XPS`. You need to use the [Worksheet.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas) to save as `XLSM`.  • Note that is very likely that if you send macro enabled files with Outlook, that they get blocked by company policies of the reciever. Macros can contain viruses and therefore are very often blocked and stripped off of emails.